# How to find and remove datetime in string, ie: Sun Mar 3, 2019 07:39AM

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a large text file which contains dates similar to

`Sun Mar 3, 2019 07:39AM`

and was wondering if there is a good way to search and remove it from the text. `AM`/`PM` could also be lowercase and may have a space in front.

Thanks

Comment: Give some sample? All date string is regular as what is above, if it is hot about regexp?

Answer (score 3):

If you know the format, you could use `regex` to locate the dates and then `strptime` if you need to get the date's value.

Comment: Thanks Scott. I guess I need to reframe my question then. How do I "convert" the above example into the `regex`?

Answer (score -1):

If you are not comfortable with regex you could try this:

```
'Sun Mar 3, 2019 07:39AM'.split()[-1].lower()
```

**Output**:

```
'07:39am'
```

I have assumed that the example you have given is a string and a uniform format is used through out your dataset.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, I have a few different dates in my text. So regex is the only way. But I am not very familiar with it.